# Recoding Similar Factor Levels Across Multiple Data Frames Using Purrr and Dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

Below are two simple data frames. I would like to re-code (collapse) the `Sat1` and `Sat2` columns so that all degrees of satisfied are coded simply as `Satisfied`, and all degrees of Dissatisfied are coded as `Dissatisfied`. Neutral will remain as Neutral. These factors will therefore have three levels - `Satisfied, Dissatisfied, and Neutral`.

I would normally accomplish this by binding the data frames, and using `lapply` along with re-code from the `car` package, such as:

```
  DF1[2:3] <- lapply(DF1[2:3], recode, c('"Somewhat Satisfied"= "Satisfied","Satisfied"="Satisfied","Extremely Dissatisfied"="Dissatisfied"........etc, etc
```

I would like to accomplish this using map functions, specifically `at_map` (to maintain the data frame, but I'm new to `purrr` so feel free to suggest other versions of map) from `purrr`, as well as `dplyr`, tidyr`,`stringr`and`ggplot2` so everything can be easily pipelined.

The example below is what I would like to accomplish, but for re-coding, but I was unable to make it work.

http://www.r-bloggers.com/using-purrr-with-dplyr/

I would like to use at_map or a similar map function so that I can keep the original columns of `Sat1` and `Sat2`, so the re-coded columns will be added to the data frame and renamed. It would be great if this step could also be included within a function.

In reality, I will have many data frames, so I only want to recode the factor levels once, and then use a function from `purrr` to make the changes across all the data frames using the least amount of code.

```
Names<-c("James","Chris","Jessica","Tomoki","Anna","Gerald")
Sat1<-c("Satisfied","Very Satisfied","Dissatisfied","Somewhat Satisfied","Dissatisfied","Neutral")
Sat2<-c("Very Dissatisfied","Somewhat Satisfied","Neutral","Neutral","Satisfied","Satisfied")
Program<-c("A","B","A","C","B","D")
Pets<-c("Snake","Dog","Dog","Dog","Cat","None")

DF1<-data.frame(Names,Sat1,Sat2,Program,Pets)

Names<-c("Tim","John","Amy","Alberto","Desrahi","Francesca")
Sat1<-c("Extremely Satisfied","Satisfied","Satisfed","Somewhat Dissatisfied","Dissatisfied","Satisfied")
Sat2<-c("Dissatisfied","Somewhat Dissatisfied","Neutral","Extremely Dissatisfied","Somewhat Satisfied","Somewhat Dissatisfied")
Program<-c("A","B","A","C","B","D")


DF2<-data.frame(Names,Sat1,Sat2,Program)
```

Comment: Do you want all your data frames combined in the end or stored in a list separately or ...?  This seems fairly straightforward with something like `mutate_each` from dplyr_0.4.3.9000 combined with `map` or `map_df`.  `map_at` looks like it replaces the current variables, so may not be the tool to use in this case.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I suppose it's ok if the data frames remain in a list separately. My main goal is to find a quick way (within the purrr dplyr pipeline) that will allow me to recode the factors across multiple data frames in one go. I like the idea of combining mutate_each and a map function. It's ok if the current variables are replaced since I can just make copies of the data frames first. So I would be grateful if you could show the code for your example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is to use `mutate_each` to do the work combined with one of the `map` functions to go through a list of data.frames.  Using `mutate_each` or equivalent from *dplyr_0.4.3.9001* allows you to rename the new columns.

You could use string manipulation instead of recoding in this case.  I believe you want to pull out `Satisfied`, `Dissatisfied`, or `Neutral` from the current strings that you have.  You can achieve this with `sub` using regular expressions.  For example,

```
sub(".*(Satisfied|Dissatisfied|Neutral).*$", "\\1", DF2$Sat2)
"Dissatisfied" "Dissatisfied" "Neutral"      "Dissatisfied" "Satisfied"    "Dissatisfied"
```

Package *stringr* has a nice function for extracting specific strings, `str_extract`.

```
library(stringr)
str_extract(DF2$Sat2, "Satisfied|Neutral|Dissatisfied")
 "Dissatisfied" "Dissatisfied" "Neutral"      "Dissatisfied" "Satisfied"    "Dissatisfied"
```

You can use this within `mutate_each` to use one of these functions on multiple columns.  The name you give for the function within `funs` is what will be added on to the new columns names.  I used `recode`.  For one of your datasets:

```
DF1 %>% 
    mutate_each( funs(recode = str_extract(., "Satisfied|Neutral|Dissatisfied") ), 
              starts_with("Sat") )

    Names               Sat1               Sat2 Program  Pets  Sat1_recode  Sat2_recode
1   James          Satisfied  Very Dissatisfied       A Snake    Satisfied Dissatisfied
2   Chris     Very Satisfied Somewhat Satisfied       B   Dog    Satisfied    Satisfied
3 Jessica       Dissatisfied            Neutral       A   Dog Dissatisfied      Neutral
4  Tomoki Somewhat Satisfied            Neutral       C   Dog    Satisfied      Neutral
5    Anna       Dissatisfied          Satisfied       B   Cat Dissatisfied    Satisfied
6  Gerald            Neutral          Satisfied       D  None      Neutral    Satisfied
```

To go through many datasets stored in a list, you can use a `map` function from *purrr* to perform a function on every element in the list.

```
list(DF1, DF2) %>%
    map(~mutate_each(.x, 
                  funs(recode = str_extract(., "Satisfied|Neutral|Dissatisfied") ), 
                  starts_with("Sat")) )

[[1]]
    Names               Sat1               Sat2 Program  Pets  Sat1_recode  Sat2_recode
1   James          Satisfied  Very Dissatisfied       A Snake    Satisfied Dissatisfied
2   Chris     Very Satisfied Somewhat Satisfied       B   Dog    Satisfied    Satisfied
...
[[2]]
      Names                  Sat1                   Sat2 Program  Sat1_recode  Sat2_recode
1       Tim   Extremely Satisfied           Dissatisfied       A    Satisfied Dissatisfied
2      John             Satisfied  Somewhat Dissatisfied       B    Satisfied Dissatisfied
...
```

Using `map_df` instead will bind all of the elements in your list into a data.frame, which may or may not be what you want.  Using the `.id` argument adds a name for each original dataset.

```
list(DF1, DF2) %>%
    map_df(~mutate_each(.x, 
                  funs(recode = str_extract(., "Satisfied|Neutral|Dissatisfied")), 
                  starts_with("Sat")), .id = "Group")

   Group     Names                  Sat1                   Sat2 Program  Pets  Sat1_recode
1      1     James             Satisfied      Very Dissatisfied       A Snake    Satisfied
2      1     Chris        Very Satisfied     Somewhat Satisfied       B   Dog    Satisfied
3      1   Jessica          Dissatisfied                Neutral       A   Dog Dissatisfied
4      1    Tomoki    Somewhat Satisfied                Neutral       C   Dog    Satisfied
5      1      Anna          Dissatisfied              Satisfied       B   Cat Dissatisfied
6      1    Gerald               Neutral              Satisfied       D  None      Neutral
7      2       Tim   Extremely Satisfied           Dissatisfied       A  <NA>    Satisfied
8      2      John             Satisfied  Somewhat Dissatisfied       B  <NA>    Satisfied
...
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: list(DF1,DF2)%>%map(~mutate(.,SatREC=Sat1 %>% recode('"Extremely Satisfied"="Satisfied"')))

Comment: Quick question, using your answer above, I also played around with using the car recode function with map and mutate, which works. The code is in the comment above. But, how would I write the same code with mutate_each, and include both Sat1 and Sat2?

Comment: As in the code in the answer, you can work on all variables that start with "Sat" using the `starts_with` function.  If you put your `recode` code in place of the `str_extract` code it should work fine.  Note the `.` in `mutate_each` represents the variable that you are mutating so you will no longer hard code the variable names like you did in your `mutate` code.

Answer (score 1):

I do big recodings like this with a join, in this case I think transforming to a long dataframe makes the problem easier to think about.

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

mdf <- DF1 %>% 
  gather(var, value, starts_with("Sat"))

recode_df <- data_frame( value = c("Extremely Satisfied","Satisfied","Somewhat Dissatisfied","Dissatisfied"),
                         recode = 1:4)
mdf <- left_join(mdf, recode_df)
mdf %>% spread(var, recode)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. It gave me some ideas since I haven't thought about using this method to recode before. However I'm still hoping for an answer that uses a purrr map function.

Comment: Ah, the pattern there is probably to write a function `f` which recodes a single vector, then use `df[] <- map_at(df, c("SAT1", "SAT2"), f)`

Comment: Yeah, that's what I want to do. I guess now I need to figure out the function. I haven't had much success creating a function to collapse the factors like in my example above. Are you able to help me out with the code?

Comment: No time right now, but for a vector `v` do something like `v[v == "Very Satisfied"] <- "Satisfied"` for each recoding step. This is part of why I think joins are easier.