# Add new variable to list of data frames with purrr and mutate() from dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

I know that there are *many* related questions here on SO, but I am looking for a purrr solution, please, not one from the apply list of functions or cbind/rbdind (I want to take this opportunity to get to know purrr better).

I have a list of dataframes and I would like to add a new column to each dataframe in the list. The value of the column will be the name of the dataframe, i.e. the name of each element in the list.

There is something similar [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37951756/recoding-similar-factor-levels-across-multiple-data-frames-using-purrr-and-dplyr), but it involves the use of a function and `mutate_each()`, whereas I need just `mutate()`.

To give you an idea of the list (called `comentarios`), here is the first line of `str()` on the first element:

```
> str(comentarios[1])
List of 1
 $ 166860353356903_661400323902901:'data.frame':    13 obs. of  7 variables:
```

So I would like my new variable to contain `166860353356903_661400323902901` for 13 lines in the result, as an ID for each dataframe.

What I am trying is:

```
dff <- map_df(comentarios, 
              ~ mutate(ID = names(comentarios)),
              .id = "Group"
              )
```

However, `mutate()` needs the name of the dataframe in order to work:

```
Error in mutate_(.data, .dots = lazyeval::lazy_dots(...)) : 
  argument ".data" is missing, with no default
```

It doesn't make sense to put in each name, I'd be straying into loop territory and losing the advantages of purrr (and R, more generally). If the list was smaller, I'd use `reshape::merge_all()`, but it has over 2000 elements. Thanks in advance for any help.

*edit: some data to make the problem reproducible, as per alistaire's comments*

```
# install.packages("tidyverse")
library(tidyverse)
df <- data_frame(one = rep("hey", 10), two = seq(1:10), etc = "etc")

list_df <- list(df, df, df, df, df)
names(list_df) <- c("first", "second", "third", "fourth", "fifth")
dfs <- map_df(list_df, 
              ~ mutate(id = names(list_df)),
              .id = "Group"
              )
```

Comment: You need to make your example [reproducible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example#5963610) by adding data.

Comment: I don't think that's necessary here, alistaire, it's a question about syntax more than anything, as Jake's answer showed.

Comment: [It is always necessary](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), or the question will be closed. [ask]

Comment: My mistake, fixed now.

Comment: Better, though you should show your desired output, as well. Assuming a bit, you can just do `dplyr::bind_rows(list_df, .id = 'id')`.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Your issue is that you have to explicitly provide reference to the data when you're not using mutate with piping. To do this, I'd suggest using `map2_df`

```
dff <- map2_df(comentarios, names(comentarios), ~ mutate(.x, ID = .y))
```

Comment: It's just map over two arguments.  The first argument is `.x` the list of dataframes, the second is `.y` which is list of dataframe names.

Comment: Sure, but I wouldn't have thought that I could do it that way, that's what I meant. This is exactly why I asked for a purrr answer, as I want to get to know the package better. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: @JakeKaupp - what is the meaning of this part: ".id = "Group". When I ommit this - the code still works fine

Comment: It was a typo and a misplaced bracket. The `. id ` was a economic variable in OP's question.

Comment: FYI, starting in *purrr_0.2.3* there is a "short-hand" family of `imap` indexed functions when you want to loop through a list and the names (or indexes) of the list simultaneously.

Answer (score 5):

using the OP's data the answer would be

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- data_frame(one = rep("hey", 10), two = seq(1:10), etc = "etc")

list_df <- list(df, df, df, df, df)
dfnames <- c("first", "second", "third", "fourth", "fifth")

dfs <- list_df %>% map2_df(dfnames,~mutate(.x,name=.y))
```